# My @Scheduled task on Spring application is not executed on Heroku

Tags: spring, heroku

In my Spring boot app, I have a task that runs every 5 minutes like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron="* 5 * * * *", zone="Europe/Paris")
public void sendPlanningDeadlineEmail() {
    // Some code
}
```

It's working fine in my local environment. But when it's deployed in Heroku server, the task is not executed.

Some ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cron expression is off. Your cron expression means: every minute `5` (so 01:05, 02:05, 03:05 etc.).

Try
`0 */5 * * * *`

See official [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--).

Answer (score 0):

The cron expression you are using is incorrect because if you are using a fixed value at minute place, it should be with fixed value of hour like 0 30 1 ? * * * to run at 1.30 am everyday.

If you want to schedule the task to run every 5 mintute use the below expression

```
0 */5 * ? * *
```

this means run At second :00, every 5 minutes starting at minute :00, of every hour.